# Java collections to create dynamic json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, collections

I need to create a json , which has an array with multiple elements. I am able to create json array dynamically and add it json object. However my situation is i would not know before hand how many array elements are going to be there. Its dynamic based on users session.
Example

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "name": "",
        "dob": "",
        "zip": ""
    },  
    "XYZ": [
        {
            "XYZ_1": "",
            "XYZ_2": "",
            "XYZ_3": "",         
        },
        {
            "XYZ_1": "",
            "XYZ_2": "",
            "XYZ_3": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

I have class A, where i collect value of XYZ_1,XYZ_2..3. I am able to collect these values as string from user. Again some processing happens and Class A is called and same set of data is collected. It is dynamic as to how many times the XYZ array elements are collected. Only at the end of the session is where i have prepare this json from say Class B and post it as json. How would i do this is Java. I tried many ways using a bean class (setter and getter). Create object array, store the array and read it at class B. But often ended up with null pointer exception. Even I couldn't make chatGPT answer me. Kindly help.

The code i have written so far.

```
@Data
public class XYZ{
private String XYZ_1;
private String XYZ_2;
private String XYZ_3; 
private static List<XYZ> myList = new ArrayList<>();
private static XYZ[] xyzArray;

public XYZ(string a, String b, String c){
    this.XYZ_1 = a;
    this.XYZ_1 = b;
    this.XYZ_1 = c;
}
public static void setXYZArray(XYZ array1) {
    myList.add(array1);
}
public static void setXYZArray2(XYZ[] array1) {
    xyzArray = array1;
}

public static XYZ[] getXYZArray() {
    return xyzArray;
}
}

Class A{
//Trying to set the values and objects to read later
public static void main(mysession){
public static XYZ[] details = new  XYZ[20];
String xyz_1=mysession.getuserValue1();
String xyz_2=mysession.getuserValue2();
String xyz_3=mysession.getuserValue3();
int counter = mysession.getCounter();

details[counter] = new XYZ (xyz_1, xyz_2, xyz_3);
XYZ.setXYZArray2(details); //try1
XYZ.setXYZArray(details[Counter]); //try2
}
}

Class B{
//trying to read the values and generate the Json
XYZ xyzDet = new XYZ();
List<XYZ> myList = xyzDet.getMyList();
XYZ[] xyzArray = XYZ.getXYZArray();
JSONObject xyzObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray xyzArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

for(XYZ details : myList)
{
    xyzObj.put("xyz_1", details.xyz_1());
    xyzObj.put("xyz_2",details.xyz_2());
    xyzObj.put("xyz_3",details.xyz_3());
    xyzArray.put(xyzObj);

}
json.put("XYZ",xyzArray)
```

Appreciate and thank you in advance.

Comment: please write the code you have tried so far , so that we can help you better

Comment: @ShilaMosammami : I have added the code to make it more easy to understand what i have tried. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to “know before hand how many array elements are going to be there”?

Comment: @Holger Oh that is because, The user can go on and on giving input of his choice. He can give multiple set of  getuserValue1 /2/3. If i knew there would be 5 times then I can declare 5objects of XYZ and access that n5number of objects in Class B. Since i don't know the value of XYZ array, i created array of XYZ objects, initially declaring the size of array to be 20.

Comment: If you think, the challenge is the dynamic number of elements, implement a working solution for a fixed number of elements and come back. We will be happy to help you then. The thing you’ve posted contains scrambled elements of the Java programming language, but not an honest attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i think the above code works , the issue was with how i am reading the Json elements in class B. Fixed it in the code